# Android Push Notification set up questions

Tags: account, configuration, android, mobilepush

We have guys on our end trying to configure Push Notifications & they’ve asked me to reach out for an answer on the below:

https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/01af36d7ba765d5231019c56880bbb9d/app_versions/21

The 'App Center' at [code.exacttarget.com](http://code.exacttarget.com) has been down all week and is blocking me from progress with the ExactTarget integration.

Another issue is that the bundle ids in the 'App Center' have a forced prefix of 'au.com.*'.  We can't change the bundle id from it's current prefix of com.* as it would cause a duplicate of the application to exist on the Google Play Store.  You will need to converse with your representative at ET to fix this.

Any idea or solutions i can go back to them with?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The bundle ids in the ExactTarget configuration do *not* need to match your application package name. As long as your app is using the app_id and access_token created in AppCenter in the call to the readyAimFire() method, they will link up just fine.